# Duvida para pegar o id de uma tabela diferente Php e MySql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Como faço para salvar o id de uma tabela diferente dentro de um select ?

Código abaixo

```
<div class="medium">
            <span>
                <select name="turma">
                    <option>Selecione a Sala</option>
                    <?php
                    do {
                        ?>
                        <option> <?php echo $exibe['sala'] ?> </option>
                    <?php } while ($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) ?>
                </select>
                <span class="icon-place"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Turma é uma tabela diferente, no formulário completo é para o cadastro de um aluno!

Comment: Isso depende da sua `query` se ela tem left join para turma

Answer (score 1):

Coloca o value do option com o id da turma. Sem ver o banco é difícil, mas suponho que seja assim:

```
<option value="<?php echo $exibe['id_turma'] ?>"> <?php echo $exibe['sala'] ?> </option>
```

Também sugiro que use o `while` ao invés do `do while`

```
<select name="turma">
    <option>Selecione a Sala</option>
    <?php
    while ($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $exibe['id_turma'] ?>"> <?php echo $exibe['sala'] ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```